# Find path of a python executable

Tags: python, path, exe, pyinstaller

I have a script which needs to be able to save its own full path into a variable.
So far I have tried:

```
sys.argv[0]
os.path.realpath(__file__)
os.path.abspath(__file__)
```

these all work with the regular python script I have. However once I convert it to an executable with pyinstaller, the above methods no longer work for getting the path of the .exe. They either detect the .exe as a .py or simply don't detect it at all. Why is this so and what method can I use that will always get the name of the script whether it is a .py or .exe. Is there a function that can get the full path of the file whether it is a normal .py file or a python .exe file. I'm on python 2.7 using windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for all file extensions .py, .exe and even if the .exe is changed to .scr the program still works:

```
import sys
import os
print os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])
```

Command line output :

```
C:\Users\angus\Desktop>t.py
C:\Users\angus\Desktop\t.py

C:\Users\angus\Desktop\dist\t>t.exe
C:\Users\angus\Desktop\dist\t\t.exe

C:\Users\angus\Desktop\dist\t>t.scr
C:\Users\angus\Desktop\dist\t\t.scr
```

Answer (score 2):

This may do the trick but if you find a better solution dont esitate to drop this.

```
import subprocess

path = subprocess.Popen('cd')
```

Answer (score 1):

This works on Py 3.4 / Win 10.

```
from win32api import GetCommandLine, GetFullPathName

print (GetCommandLine())

print (GetFullPathName('temp.exe'))
```

Output:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.15063]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\scratch\dist\temp>temp
temp
C:\scratch\dist\temp\temp.exe

C:\scratch\dist\temp>
```

I displayed the command line because you might have to perform additional steps to isolate the script's file name for use in `GetFullPathName`.

Edit: I made a correction! Since I knew the name of the script (temp.py) I knew the name that pyinstaller would assign to the executable (temp.exe), and I could use `GetFullPathName` against it.